# Angular js - Error: [$parse:lval] Trying to assign a value to a non l-value

Tags: angularjs

I have an error in this line of my code, but the code fulfills its mission. 
I do not understand what can happen. I am very new with angular

```
<md-list-item ng-show="cargando == false" ng-repeat="idea in ideas2 = (ideas | orderBy : '-Created' | filter: filterData | filter:buscaAprobadas)" ng-class="md-1-line && { evaluada: idea.Estado !='Aprobada'} " ng-click="idea.Estado != 'Aprobada' || idea.selected = !idea.selected">
```

Comment: What is md-1-line? You have error in your ng-class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your last comparison: `idea.selected = !idea.selected` is an assignment. You want to change it to `idea.selected == !idea.selected` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was my problem.

Comment: No problem. You should accept the answer to specify that.

Comment: Wouldn't idea.selected == !idea.selected always return false?

Comment: I did wonder about that. I'm not sure what the OP is trying to accomplish with it, but the use of an assignment there was definitely the cause of the error in question.

Comment: I use x = !x all the time to reverse booleans. I think he wanted to unselect the selected idea after the ng-click, but he needed to use && instead of ||.