# Trying to assign a value to a non l-value - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a condition, in my Angular app, in the view which disables the click event if false is returned, like so:

```
<li data-ng-click="!$ctrl.question.q1 || activeTab = 1" data-ng-disabled="!$ctrl.question.q1">Q.1</li>
<li data-ng-click="!$ctrl.question.q2 || activeTab = 2" data-ng-disabled="!$ctrl.question.q2">Q.2</li>
```

If `question.q2` returns false, don't change the value of `activeTab` and remain disabled. The function works, however an error displays in the console:

```
Trying to assign a value to a non l-value
```

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484248/angular-js-error-parselval-trying-to-assign-a-value-to-a-non-l-value), which explains how I am assigning a value rather than comparing it, but I need to assign it to change what is displayed in a seperate panel. The tab functionality worked fine before adding the condition.

***Question***

How do I resolve the this error?

```
<uib-tabset active="activeTab">
    <uib-tab heading="" index="1" data-ng-hide="true">
       //content
    </uib-tab> 
    <uib-tab heading="" index="2" data-ng-hide="true">
       //content
    </uib-tab> 
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: Post your script code also

Comment: `!$ctrl.question.q1 || activeTab = 1` is an invalid left-hand side assignment. What do you mean by using `||` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic inside `data-ng-click` is reading as "NOT $ctrl.question.q2 OR assign activeTab value 2"

I think what you want is a shorthand if statement in there, using the ternary operator as such:

`data-ng-click="activeTab = $ctrl.question.q2 ? 2 : activeTab"`

Which reads as: "Assign value 2 to activeTab if $ctrl.question.q2 is true, or assign it it's old value if $ctrl.question.q2 is false"

Comment: Thank you! All working now. I was following another guide which left me a bit confused.